# Usage of "that's good to know"

Tags: phrase-usage

While having smalltalk, is it okay to say "that's good to know" when someone says they're doing great?

For example:

- How are you doing?
- I am doing great
- That's good to know!

Is the last phrase appropriate in this situation? Does it sound good?

Answer (score 1):

There's no set response.  "That's good to know" is fine.

I suspect that it is more likely either that 1) Person B will ask a question,
so the conversation will go something like "How are you doing? / Great, how about you?..."  Or Person A will actually want to say something else. The "How are you doing?" question is just a conversation starter, and so the conversation will go "How are you doing?/ Great /Say, can I borrow your ..." or something else.

But there is nothing *wrong* with "that's good to know", even though it does rather close the dialogue.  What is B supposed to say back?

Comment: That's good to know can also sound sarcastic at times.